# What is an adjective to express a woman who keeps arguing, never listening to, often scream at them, and create a very bad noisy environment?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A woman never tries to create a peaceful environment, people give her some good reasonable advice but she keeps arguing, never listening to, often scream at them, and create a very bad noisy environment.

**What is an adjective for it in everyday conversation, e.g. "*you are very shrewish*"?**

I am thinking about "[sharp-ˈtongued](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sharp-tongued)"

> adjective [usually before noun]
>
> saying things in a disapproving or unfriendly way which often upsets
> people
>
> his sharp-tongued wife"

Comment: Why have you explicitly limited your context to a ***woman**?* It seems more than a bit "sexist" to assume that there won't be any ***men*** like this.

Comment: mean
nasty
spiteful
malicious
disagreeable
bitter
poisonous
venomous
ill-tempered
bad-tempered
ill-humoured
moody
irritable
irascible
surly
sullen
peevish
petulant
cross
fractious
crabbed
crabby
tetchy
testy
grouchy
waspish
perverse
...

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, what about "sharp-ˈtongued" adjective [usually before noun]    
saying things in a disapproving or unfriendly way which often upsets people.
Eg, "his sharp-tongued wife"

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, there is a link on the internet ":What is a sharp tongued woman?" https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+sharp-tongued&oq=define%3A+sharp-tongued&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1934j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: There are a number of words in this general area that *are* specifically or primarily used of women. Googling [synonym **harridan**](https://www.google.com/search?q=synonym+harridan&oq=synonym+harridan&aqs=chrome..69i57.244284j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), for example, returns **shrew
virago
harpy
termagant
vixen
nag
hag
crone
dragon
ogress
fishwife
hellcat
she-devil
fury
gorgon**. Take your pick. Or **sharp-tongued** if you like that one better for an adjective (it's not *specifically* female-oriented though).

Comment: The classic term would be "scold" (a noun, not an adjective) now rather old-fashioned if not obsolete.